# How to distinguish sever responses from announcement messages the server sends when using twisted library?

Tags: python, twisted

The situation is that I want to make client application which connects to a server (it is a custom TCP protocol), maintain persistent connection and at occasions send some requests, receive responses. So far something that I can achieve easily with python twisted library.

However, in this case the server is quite chatty, and can decide at any time that it will send an announcement message to all its connected clients. From the protocol point of view, there is a field (let's call it `packetid`) in the packet header that allows me to match request responses, and to distinguish the announcement packets from those, no problem from protocol point of view.

Now I am thinking how to implement code that will be able to handle this, to distinguish incoming responses from server announcements. My idea is to simply maintain a dictionary in the custom `Protocol` implementation, and store the `Deferred` objects there for each request (`packetid` would be the key). Once I receive individual message through `receivedData`, I use the `packetid` field given in my packet to lookup in the dictionary, and call corresponding callbacks for corresponding `Deferred`, if it is a response to some of previous requests, otherwise react to it as a server announcement message.

Is this solution alright, or is there some better solution, perhaps utilizing some of the already provided twisted mechanism? Also is there some existing protocol that has same characteristics, a protocol that needs within same connection to distinguish responses from other messages (so that I could inspire by its implementation)?

Comment: Sounds about right.  Also, IMAP4 works this way and has a Twisted implementation.  AMP is also somewhat similar (it doesn't have announcements but it has symmetric request/response).

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Looking at the implementation of those protocols, that is exactly what I needed, thank you!